# Error Cypress : > (0 , _cypressCucumberPreprocessor.And) is not a function

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-intercept, cypress-custom-commands

i got this error message while trying to run my test using Cypress/Cucumber
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19r3y.png)
i already imported and keyword in all my files and i already installed all the dependecies.
Any ideas?
Ali.

i tried to run the tests in cypress

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

---

run :

> npm i --force

after that you can run :

> npx cypress open